# How to step into a C++ DLL source file from a Delphi application while debugging

Tags: delphi, debugging, visual-c++, delphi-7

My Delphi module uses a C++ DLL function. While debugging in the Delphi [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), I need to step into a C++ function in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not possible. Only one debugger can be attached to the process at a time, so while Delphi is stepping through the Delphi module, Visual Studio cannot debug the DLL.

Your only hope is if you have [C++Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder) installed. Then you can let it debug both the Delphi module and the DLL from within a single IDE instance.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a third party dll with no source and symbol you are out of luck 
it it is your own dll builded with VC you can set the delphi exe as the  process that load the DLL